# Symfony: send failed messages via email

Tags: php, symfony, message-queue, symfony5

I have a simple messanger config:

```yaml
framework:
    messenger:
        failure_transport: failed
        transports:
            async:
                dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
                retry_strategy:
                    max_retries: 2
                    delay: 10000
            failed: 'doctrine://default?queue_name=failed'

        routing:
            someInterface: async
```

I would like to know about every message routed to failed transport f.e. system should send email notification to me when message is redirecting. My only idea is to periodically review `messenger_messages` table which contains messages stored in failed transport but imao it's not symfony-way solution. Do you know more clever solution for this feature?

I am using symfony/messenger with version 5.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ultimately, I applied the solution below:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Author: writ3it
 */

namespace App\Maintenance\Messenger;


use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Event\WorkerMessageFailedEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\MessageBusInterface;

class FailedMessageListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    /**
     * @var MessageBusInterface
     */
    private MessageBusInterface $bus;

    public function __construct(MessageBusInterface $bus)
    {
        $this->bus = $bus;
    }

    public function onMessageFailed(WorkerMessageFailedEvent $event)
    {
        if ($event->willRetry()) {
            return;
        }
        $envelope = $event->getEnvelope();
        $message = $envelope->getMessage();

        $subject = sprintf("Message added to failed transport. Message: %s", \get_class($message));
        $content = serialize($message);

        $notification = new FailedMessageNotificationEvent();
        $notification->setSubject($subject)
            ->setContent($content);
        $this->bus->dispatch($notification);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            WorkerMessageFailedEvent::class => ['onMessageFailed', -256],
        ];
    }
}
```

`FailedMessageNotificationEvent` is a message that will be caught by my mailing handler. The `FailedMessageListener` class should be tagged as `kernel.event_subscriber` or autoconfigured.

I didn't use middleware because messenger sends messages to the failed transport directly, without middlewares.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your solution, could specify why -90 as priority  on your event listener ?

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, it will help more people in the future.

Comment: @Famas23 Today, I have no idea :) I think, the best choice is -256 (or less) because Symfony is using range +/-256 internally and this subscriber should be executed as last.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do it through configuration, but you create your custom middleware and send email by yourself. https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#middleware

You can check `FailedMessageProcessingMiddleware` for reference https://github.com/symfony/messenger/blob/master/Middleware/FailedMessageProcessingMiddleware.php